# Apache CXF (2.6.1): Client gets "Content is not allowed in prolog"

Tags: web-services, apache, jaxb, cxf, xmlbeans

I'm using Apache CXF (2.6.1) in my java application to consume 3rd party Web Service. But I have a problem with it, in particular if I use JAXB for databinding while stubs generation my client will always send requests with "header" like "--uuid:e47f145b-38f7-4402-8eec-657d71bc8ad4..." (see client request below), i.e. besides XML part there is some special info...

It looks like this special info causes error reply from server "Content is not allowed in prolog" (see server response below), i.e. server is not expecting such body. What is interesting here is that if I generate stubs using XMLBEANS for databinding everything starts to work just fine (and there is no such "special" info in request body, only XML). After some googling I suspect that my client for some reason tries to use MTOM (with JAXB) and I don't know how to turn it off. I've already tried the following to turn MTOM off (with no luck):

```
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("mtom-enabled", Boolean.FALSE);
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("write.attachments", Boolean.FALSE);
((BindingProvider)port).setMTOMEnabled(false);
```

Please help I would really want to move to JAXB since it's much more compact in comparison with XMLBEANS...

**Client code:**

```
AdminServiceV2 ws = new AdminServiceV2();
AdminV2 port = ws.getAdminPortV2();

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy();
authorizationPolicy.setUserName("user1");
authorizationPolicy.setPassword("password1");
authorizationPolicy.setAuthorizationType("Basic");
http.setAuthorization(authorizationPolicy); 

try {
    port.getUsersInfo("user1");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Client request:**

```
--uuid:e47f145b-38f7-4402-8eec-657d71bc8ad4
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:getUsersInfo xmlns:ns2="http://service.admin.ws.five9.com/v2/"><userNamePattern>user1</userNamePattern></ns2:getUsersInfo></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--uuid:e47f145b-38f7-4402-8eec-657d71bc8ad4--
```

**Server response:**

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><env:Header></env:Header><env:Body><env:Fault xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><faultcode>env:Client</faultcode><faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.</faultstring></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Thanks,
Konstantin

Answer (score 1):

No CXF request ever starts normally with --uuid. That is part-way through a multi-part HTTP message. With or without MTOM, a normal SOAP message consists of an HTTP header followed by the XML content. If it's MTOM, the HTTP header declared multipart, and then there are multipart separators and sub-headers.

If you are using a custom front-end to ask for 'plain XML' messages without the usual required HTTP headers, then that, combined with MTOM, might have the undesirable effect at hand.

JAXB will generally only enable MTOM if you have `@XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")` annotations(s). You should also look at the WSDL/XSD for the service and see if it has xmime annotations in there.

See [the CXF MTOM doc](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/mtom-attachments-with-jaxb.html) for more details.

You haven't specified the CXF version or how you configured your CXF client endpoint. You might get better assistance by sending all that data to the CXF user mailing list.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply, I've updated post with info you've mentioned (cxf version, client code).

Comment: Are you really sure that this is all the data on the wire, and no headers about the --? Have you turned on CXF logging interceptors on the client side?

Comment: Yes, that's all code I have. I've checked for the annotations in my wsdl - nothing found. Logging interceptors doesn't show much new (I can't understand why it's multipart): Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 1
Address: https://api.someserver.com/wsadmin/v2/AdminWebService
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/xml"; boundary="uuid:c0848dcb-39a2-4d0e-ba71-c28fa123895f"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml"
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], Authorization=[Basic a2JhYnVzaGtpbjpyb290MTIz], SOAPAction=[""]}
--------------------------------------

Comment: I guess that's something in wsdl that making it multipart: <xs:complexType name='getUserInfo'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='userName' type='xs:string'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts, sorry I leave this question as answered by Dan Kulp (see below).

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered on CXF user mailing list by Daniel Kulp, for details see
http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Apache-CXF-2-6-1-Client-gets-Content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-td5713009.html#a5713055. In short the problem was with WSDL (it contains swaRefs) that forces CXF to send messages like with attachments. Workaround was also provided...